# Connecting MYSQL DB using jaydebeapi using Python

Tags: python, mysql, jpype, jaydebeapi

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL DB from Python prompt and using JayDeBeApi. Below is the piece of code I'm using:

```
"**Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jpype
>>> import jaydebeapi
>>> import os
>>> jar = "/tmp/:/usr/share/java/"
>>> os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] ="/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64"
>>> os.environ['CLASSPATH'] =jar
>>> args='-Djava.class.path=%s' % jar
>>> jvm_path = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
>>> jpype.startJVM(jvm_path, args)
/home/aarpan_roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_core.py:218: UserWarning: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deprecated: convertStrings was not specified when starting the JVM. The default
behavior in JPype will be False starting in JPype 0.8. The recommended setting
for new code is convertStrings=False.  The legacy value of True was assumed for
this session. If you are a user of an application that reported this warning,
please file a ticket with the developer.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  """)
>>> database_host='<MySQL DB HOST>'
>>> database_user='<MySQL DB USER>'
>>> database_password='<MySQL DB PASSWORD>'
>>> database_port='<MySQL DB PORT>'
>>> database_db='<MySQL DB DATABASE>'
>>> jclassname = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>>> url = "jdbc:mysql://{host}:{port}/{database}".format(host=database_host, port=database_port, database=database_db)
>>> driver_args = [url, database_user, database_password]
>>> jars = ["/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar","/usr/share/java/mysql.jar"]
>>> libs = None
>>> cnx = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars=jars, libs=libs)**
```

But, I'm getting below error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "<Home_PATH>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/**init**.py", line 412, in connect
jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
File "<HOME_PATH>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/**init**.py", line 221, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
jpype.JClass(jclassname)
File "<HOME_PATH>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jclass.py", line 130, in **new**
return _JClassNew(args[0], **kwargs)
File "<HOME_PATH>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jclass.py", line 228, in _JClassNew
javaClass = _jpype.PyJPClass(arg)
jpype._jclass.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
"

Can you please help me understand where I'm missing something and what needs to be corrected here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot spot the proper mysql driver JAR on your specified classpath. Therefore you get the ClassNotFoundException you are seeing. Try to specify the exact path to it.